# Compute the area of a geodesic triangle on a cone

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

I'd like to compute the area of the triangle bounded by the three geodesics that form the triangle $T$ of vertices $(0,1,1),(2,0,2),(0,-1,1)$ on the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$ in $\Bbb R^3$.

The question seems suited for the Gauss Bonnet theorem, though the Gaussian curvature of the cone is zero, so I don't think you can apply it here.

Then there's the option of pulling back the area on $\Bbb R^2$ and integrating using the standard formula
$$A(T) = \int_{x^{-1}(T)} \sqrt{EG-F^2}dudv$$
though to know the shape of $T$ you'd have to compute the euqations of the geodesics that bound it, which would be pretty hard and labourious.

Is there any shortcut to this? Like the cone being locally isometric to $\Bbb R^2$ or something?

Comment: Thought out of the blue - I haven't checked. The cone is developable. Can you unroll it flat, then see the lengths of the geodesics, which will be line segments. Then use Heron's formula.

Comment: Yes, I did check. The geodesics on the cone are straight lines (in the Euclidean sense) after unrolling. But you don't have to unroll in order to use the Heron formula. If you are a creature on the surface of the cone, don't worry, in that case you just measure the length of the sides.